mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000) on python
My code:
cursor = cnx.cursor()
xlsx = pd.read_excel('online_retail.xlsx')
for index, row in xlsx.iterrows():
    values = [row['Invoice'],
              row['StockCode'],
              row['Description'],
              row['Quantity'],
              row['InvoiceDate'],
              row['Price'],
              row['Customer ID'],
              row['Country']]
    INSERT_INTO = (f"INSERT INTO online_retail.registers VALUES {values[0]}, "
                   f"{values[1]}, "
                   f"{values[2]}, "
                   f"{values[3]}, "
                   f"{values[4]}, "
                   f"{values[5]}, "
                   f"{values[6]}, "
                   f"{values[7]}")
    cursor.execute(INSERT_INTO)

My database schema:
CREATE TABLE online_retail.registers (
    invoice INT NOT NULL,
    stock_code VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    quantity INT ,
    invoice_date DATETIME(0),
    price FLOAT,
    customer_ID INT,
    country VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY(invoice)
);

Data example:
Data in text
Error:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '489434, 85048, 15CM CHRISTMAS GLASS BALL 20 LIGHTS, 12, 2009-12-01 07:45:00, 6.9' at line 1
Why i am getting this error and how can i proceed?
How can i solve this problem?

You're missing the ( after VALUES.

Also, your code is wide open to SQL injection. See how to use variables in SQL

If you printed INSERT_INTO I think you would have seen the problem immediately. What debugging did you do?

This helped me, and your sugestion about this security issue carried me to use the to_sql() method, and it worked fine. Thank you!

In SQL, each collection of data items in VALUES clause requires opening and closing parentheses. Also, by omitting columns in INSERT INTO clause, the query relies on ordinal position of columns that can raise errors if new columns are added or old columns removed. Consider explicitly declaring columns. And for safer and faster processing, consider parameterization with cursor.executemanyusing pandas' to_numpy() and numpy's tolist() for list of column value lists:
retail_df = pd.read_excel('online_retail.xlsx')

cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql = (
    "INSERT INTO online_retail.registers ("
    "   invoice, stock_code, description, quantity,"
    "   invoice_date, price, customer_ID, country) "
    "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
)

values = (
    retail_df.reindex(
        [
            'Invoice', 'StockCode', 'Description', 'Quantity', 
            'InvoiceDate', 'Price', 'Customer ID', 'Country'
        ], 
        axis = "columns"
    ).to_numpy().tolist()
)

cursor.executemany(sql, values)


That worked, but it raised a error when python tried to insert timestamp values in time column. After this i searched a lot and decided to use the to_sql() method. And it worked fine, but thank you!

Try converting timestamp to ANSI date format before creating values: retail_df["InvoiceDate"] = retail_df["InvoiceDate"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").
